# Understanding how to return errors immediately in a distributed system for payment

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, stripe-payments, payment, distributed

A common architecture for handling high volume of payment, e.g. if you're a food delivery app, is a pub/sub architecture with some kind of distributed messaging, e.g. Kafka. The consumer then calls a third-party payment processor. There are often cases in which the third-party payment processor may time-out or might be down so there is additional setup to handle retries. A DB is also usually involved to keep track of payment status, e.g. having an additional consumer setup the record in the DB. A question I am having trouble wrapping my head around is in the case there is a legitimate error, e.g. card details are incorrect, how can this error be returned to the user and in a timely way? We probably don't want to give the user a success message immediately, and then later give them an error?

Answer (score 0):

Payment flows should be strongly consistent, the user needs to know (before leaving the page) if the payment happened or not. There are 2 approaches I can think of on how to achieve that:

- If you have an event-driven architecture, you can create dedicated queues for payment request/response and make sure the bottleneck is in the third-party payment processor, and not somewhere in your system. The front-end can just poll for the results (in an async way, of course) and inform the user consistently about the payment status.
- If that's feasible, you can use request-response model that is already by design in HTTP/gRPC, the approach mentioned above basically does the same thing, but in an event-driven world. So instead of putting a message on a queue, the API Gateway calls directly the payment microservice.